# Can't replace backslash in a string with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I need to replace all backslashes in a string with another symbol. I use regex for that, but it just doesn't work

```
const name = 'AC\DC'; 
const replaced = icon.replace(/\\/g, "-");

console.log(name);
console.log(replaced);

// ACDC
// ACDC
```

For example, in this string the backslash is not replaced and not even shown when I log the origial string in a console.

I get such strings from external source so I can't escape the backslash or use another character.

Comment: Because there's no backslash in `name`. Your replace method works as it is when the string (`icon`!) actually contains a backslash.

Answer (score 1):

When you have backslash character in a string, it is used to escape next character. Just like how you use to escape the backslash in your regex. To correctly test this, you should do use name like this:

```
const name = "AC\\DC";

console.log(name);
console.log(name.replace(/\\/g, "-"));
```

Comment: btw You have an extra backslash in your example log output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the first line to `"AC\\DC"` as follows since "" is an escape character, you will never get a "" in `console.log(name)`.

```
const name = 'AC\\DC'; 
const replaced = name.replace(/\\/g, "-");

console.log(name);
console.log(replaced);
```